# "Segmentation fault" when open an existing file

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

When I'm running a simple code as:

```
program summation
implicit none
integer :: sum, a, b

print*, "This program performs summations. Enter 0 to stop."

!open(unit=10, file="SumData.DAT", status='replace', action='write',iostat=b, err=100)
!100 continue
!write(*,*) b

open(unit=10, file="SumData.DAT", status='replace', action='write')

sum = 0

do
 print*, "Add:"
 read*, a
 if (a == 0) then
  exit
 else
  sum = sum + a
 end if
  write(10,*) a
end do

print*, "Summation =", sum
write(10,*) "Summation =", sum
close(10)

end
```

When I firstly run this code, it was ok and it generated the `SumData.dat` file. But when I run it again, it will stop at the open command and show following error:

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
>
> Backtrace for this error:
> #0  ffffffffffffffff
> #1  ffffffffffffffff
> #2  ffffffffffffffff
> #3  ffffffffffffffff
> #4  ffffffffffffffff
> #5  ffffffffffffffff
> #6  ffffffffffffffff
> #7  ffffffffffffffff
> #8  ffffffffffffffff
> #9  ffffffffffffffff
> #10  ffffffffffffffff
> #11  ffffffffffffffff
> #12  ffffffffffffffff
> #13  ffffffffffffffff
> #14  ffffffffffffffff
> #15  ffffffffffffffff
> #16  ffffffffffffffff
> #17  ffffffffffffffff
> #18  ffffffffffffffff
> ```

If I delete the `SumData.dat` file and run it again, it was ok. Does anyone know why the program cannot open existing files?

Comment: Please use the generic [tag:fortran] tag unless your problem is specific to a certain version of the Fortran Standard. You certainly don't want to restrict yourself to a 25 year old version of Fortran.

Comment: How does the datafile look like?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, if there is no data file, the program will create one and the summation results will be written in it as:            
           1
           1
 Summation =           2

Comment: have you really the exact same error with the different options? Is this really the entire code?

Comment: @agentp
Hi, yes. They showed the same error and they both stopped at the open command. The code above is the one I'm running.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to specify exactly what you are trying to do with the file:

```
open(unit=10, file="SumData.DAT", status='replace', action='write')
```

With this, you specify that you are trying open a file for writing, replacing it if necessary. If you do not specify `status`, the compiler is free to do whatever it deems best - this might lead to your failure. The same holds true for the `action specifier`.

Additionally, you should use `iostat=<some integer var>` to check for the return value of the `open` operation. Then, you can avoid ugly runtime errors as you experience.

Comment: Hi Alexander, many thanks for your answer. And sorry for my unprofessional code format.  
I tried your suggestion but it still shows the same errors.  
Then I tried to use IOSTAT and ERR as follow:
    open(unit=10, file="SumData.DAT", status='replace', action='write', iostat=b, err=100)
    100 continue
    write(*,*) b

The program still stopped at the open command. Could you please give me some more suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue whilst trying to use `gfortran` version 5.1.0, which ships with Code::Blocks 17.12. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/mxe/mxe/issues/689) it seems to be a problem with the version.

> [...] whatever the issue was it's fixed with GCC 5.2.

Code to recreate, in `main.f90`:

```
program main
  IMPLICIT NONE
  OPEN(10, FILE='tmp.dat', STATUS='OLD', ACTION='WRITE')
  CLOSE(10)
end program main
```

compiled with

```
gfortran -Wall -o a.out main.f90
```

and running

```
touch tmp.dat && ./a.out
```

Returns

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  ffffffff
```